# Issue with custom header (scene.route is undefined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to have a custom header component in react native navigation 5, however I'm getting the following error:

```
TyperError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'scene.route')
```

In my component:

```
export default CustomHeader2 = (props) => 
{
  const {scene, previous, navigation } = props;


    return (
    <View style={{ width:'100%',height:50, flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'space-between', backgroundColor:'white' }}>
        <View style={{ height:50, flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center' }}>
        {previous ? 
        (<TouchableOpacity onPress={ ()=>{ navigation.goBack() } } style={{ width:50, height:'100%',flexDirection:'column',alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center' }}>
            <MaterialCommunityIcon name="arrow-left" style={{ color:'black', marginRight:0, fontSize:30 }}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>)
        :null
        }
        <Text style={{ fontSize:18, color:'rgb(68,68,68)',fontWeight:'bold' }}>{ scene.route.params.venue.name }</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
    );

};
```

In my stack:

```
<Stack.Screen
            name="VenueCard8"
            component={VenueCard8}
            headerShown={true} 
            options={({ route }) => ({ title: route.params.venue.name, header: () => (<CustomHeader2></CustomHeader2>) })}
            
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

screen options

```
      options={() => ({
        header: (props) => (
          <CustomHeader
            {...props}
          />
        )
      })}
```

custom header:

```
const CustomHeader = (props) => {
  console.log('props = ', props);
  console.log('scene = ', props.scene);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Hello</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
export default CustomHeader2 = (props) => {

    return (
    .........
        <Text style={.....}>{ props.route.params.venue.name }</Text>
    ......
    );
};
```